# Laravel cant send mail: "Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required ↵""

Tags: angular, laravel

I am trying to send automatic email after registration using Gmail , Angular-7 frontend and  backend. I got this error:

```
exception: "Swift_TransportException"
    file: 
 "C:\xampp\htdocs\customer_portal\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php"
line: 457
message: "Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
↵""
```

I tried to change the **.env** in Laravel to this, but the problem is still there

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

This is the code:

```
public function returnResponse($success, $data, $errorCode = 0, $message = false) {
        $response = array();
        $response['success'] = $success;
        $response['message'] = isset($message) ? $message : '';
        if ($errorCode) {
            $response['errorCode'] = isset($errorCode) ? $errorCode : 0;
        }
        $response['data'] = $data;
        return response()->json($response, 200);
}

public function createClientQuote(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'client_name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'business_name' => 'required',
                    'truck_required' => 'required',
                    'quote_origin' => 'required',
                    'quote_destination' => 'required',
                    'commodity' => 'required',  
                    'weight' => 'required',
                    'loading_date' => 'required',                                     
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->returnResponse(false, ['error' => $validator->errors()], 1, 'Invalid Quote Data');
        }
        $input = $request->all();

        $success = array();
        $clientquote = new ClientQuote;

                $mainData = array();
                $mainData['to'] = $input['email'];
                $mainData['from'] = "mymail@gmail.com";
                $mainData['subject'] = "Quote";
                $mainData['content'] = "You have successfully sent a Quote, we will get back to you. Thanks";
                $this->mailSend($mainData);
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['client_name'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['email'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['phone'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['business_name'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['truck_required'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['quote_destination'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['commodity'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['weight'];
        $clientquote->client_name = $input['loading_date'];
        $clientquote->save();
        return $this->returnResponse(true, array(), 0, 'Client added successfully.');
    }
```

I expected an email to be sent, but it brings error:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.change mail driver

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

2.clear config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```